# How to find Bluetooth stack name in windows xp sp2?

Tags: windows-xp, bluetooth, sp2

I have an acer laptop and I installed Windows xp sp2.

I want to find Bluetooth stack name in my laptop (ie) `WIDCOMM/Microsoft Bluetooth` stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check "Add/Remove Programs".
2. Open Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`).

   - If you see a category "Bluetooth *Radios*" and under it a "Microsoft Bluetooth Enumerator", it's Microsoft's stack.
   - If you see "Bluetooth *Devices*" *without* the "Enumerator", it's Widcomm.

   Note: Windows Update can remove the Widcomm stack and install Microsoft, if you download the Bluetooth update.

---

Speaking of Windows Update... Using XP without SP3 is not the best idea.